# Can one use memset to fill an array of std::complex<float>s?

Tags: c++, std, fill, complex-numbers, memset

Specifically, I'm wondering if this line:

```
memset(cjzyp,(0,0),size_cjzy*sizeof(std::complex<float>));
```

will fill `cjzyp`, an array of `complex<float>`s, with the complex zero value (`(0,0)`).

Comment: memset(cjzyp,(0,0),size_cjzy*sizeof(std::complex<float>));  

Sorry there seems to be an error with the above line of code where the <float> was omitted.  Above is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::memset` takes as second parameter an int converted to an unsigned char, it won't work. Use `std::fill` instead

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/

```
cjzyp = new std::complex<float>[100]
std::fill(cjzyp, cjzyp + 100, std::complex<float>(-1.0, 0.0));
delete [] cjzyp;
```